# How to make nant build 32 bit assemblies

Tags: nant

I have a Visual Studio project that was originally configured to build using the Release|Any CPU build configuration.

I need to change this so all the assemblies are built using Release|x86.

I can change this in Visual Studio but how do I specify the equivalent in my nant build script?

**EDIT**: I am building my assemblies using the csc task.

Comment: Are you building using the `csc` task, `msbuild` task or `solution` task?

Comment: skolima - I have edited my original question with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience might be outdated (did this 3 years ago), but the [NAnt `<csc>` documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/csc.html) still supports it: this is not possible in a simple way.

We've solved this by running [`corflags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the output assembly after build to set the `32BIT` flag. You can do this from NAnt, with the `<exec>` task. `CorFlags` is installed as part of the SDK, so you should have it already.

Comment: Thanks skolima.  Using corflags works and I will put execute as part of the nant build

Answer (score 0):

I am using nant 0.92 version. I have solved the problem using platform attribute of csc/vbc compiler tag.

```
<csc target="library" output="xxxx.dll" platform="x86" verbose="true" debug="true">
<vbctarget="library" output="xxxx.dll" platform="x86" verbose="true" debug="true">
```